# Diffrence between bias and training error regarding to KNN

Tags: machine-learning, classification, bias, k-nearest-neighbour

So I'll ask my question by presenting another question,

Which of the following statements regarding the k-nearest neighbors classifier for samples in $\mathcal{X} = 
\mathbb{R}^d$ is true?

(a) The variance of the classifier increases when k increases

(b) The training error of the classifier increases when k increases

(c) The bias of the classifier increases when k increases

The answer to this is: (c)

I know that (a) is definitely false, but I while I was wondering why (b) is incorrect, I thought to myself what is the difference between Bias and training error?

So I think the answer is that the bias is calculated by: (TP + TN) / (P + N)

While the training error is something like that: $1/m\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{m} Loss(y_i,\hat{y_i})$

Assuming I have m training samples.

So to sum it up, why (b) is not true, and are my definitions correct?